# How to s3 object URL that works with cloudfront?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently storing files privately on S3. In my Rails app, in the attachment.rb model I can obtain a public URL for the private file like so:

```
def cdn_url ( style='original' )
  attachment.s3_object(style).url_for( :read, secure: true, response_content_type: self.meta['file_content_type'], expires: 1.hour ).to_s
end
```

The problem is this is providing a URL to S3 and rewriting the URL to use my Cloudfront origin url is erroring with:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

How can I get a public URL asset like below but serve the asset via Cloudfront?

Comment: Can you share an example of the url generated via `cdn_url` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First Way (Easy)

Just use [`aws_cf_signer`](https://github.com/dylanvaughn/aws_cf_signer) gem. Put it in you bundler.

WIth this you can do something like

```
def cdn_url (options = {})
  style = options[:style] || 'original'
  cloudfront_domain =  options[:cloudfront_domain] || 'example.cloudfront.net'
  cloudfront_pem_key_path = options[:cloudfront_pem_key_path]
  cloudfront_key_paid_id = options[:cloundfrount_key_paid_id] 
  path = attachment.path(style)  #path of the file
  # you can get this values from your aws a/c , most probably by going int 
  # https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential      
  signer = AwsCfSigner.new(cloudfront_pem_key_path, cloudfront_key_paid_id)
  # this configuration may vary. 
  # visit https://github.com/dylanvaughn/aws_cf_signer 
  # and check all available settings/options   
  url = signer.sign(path, :ending => Time.now + 3600)
  cloudfront_domain + url
end
```

With this you can access the url with something like this

```
  cdn_url(cloudfront_pem_key_path: '/users/downloads/pri.pem' , cloudfront_key_paid_id: '33243424XXX')
```

## Second way

```
# A simple function to return a signed, expiring url for Amazon Cloudfront. 
# This will require openssl, digest/sha1, base64 and maybe other libraries. 
 
module CloudFront
  def get_signed_expiring_url(domain,path, expires_in, private_key_filename, key_pair_id)
 
    # AWS works on UTC, so make sure you are not using local time
    expires = (Time.now.getutc + expires_in).to_i.to_s
 
    private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(private_key_filename))
 
    # path should be your S3 path without a leading slash and without a file extension.
    # e.g. files/private/52
    policy = %Q[{"Statement":[{"Resource":"#{path}","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":#{expires}}}}]}]
    signature = Base64.strict_encode64(private_key.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, policy))
 
    # I'm not sure exactly why this is required, but it's in Amazon's perl script and seems necessary
    # Different base64 implementations maybe? 
    signature.tr!("+=/", "-_~")
    
    "#{domain}#{path}?Expires=#{expires}&Signature=#{signature}&Key-Pair-Id=#{key_pair_id}"
  end
end
```

With this you can do something like

```
def cdn_url ( style='original',cloudfront_pem_key_path,key_pair_id)
  path = attachment.path(style)  #path of the file
  # you can get this values from your aws a/c , most probably by going int 
  CloudFront.get_signed_expiring_url 'example.cloudfront.net', path, 45.seconds ,'/users/downloads/pri.pem', 'as12XXXXX')
end
```

Give a try, may be it will work. Be sure to properly set properly bucket access policy. check this out if you are seeing `accessDenied` error http://www.jppinto.com/2011/12/access-denied-to-file-amazon-s3-bucket/

Comment: This is really great. The challenge with this is, I have an existing S3 bucket that I'm using currently on production. To get a PEM key I need to update that s3 bucket to only be accessed by Cloudfront, not S3 directly which would break everything. Is there a way to get Cloudfront and S3 both working so I don't break what's live? Thanks

Comment: Cloudfront doesn't care whether s3 files are directly accessible or not. You just have to allow cloudfront to allow to access s3, that's all. Just visit this link https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential and get your pem key. There is nothing like what you are saying

Comment: How do I allow cloudfront to access S3?

Comment: Also, any steps on how to get a pem? Any tutorials to get a pem that provides just the required access?

Comment: First get private key and and its id by going to your aws credential page. This is how i get it http://cl.ly/VtMW. it is very easy. then you have to create new/edit cloudfront distribution so it can access your bucket files. It is easy, just do http://cl.ly/image/463w2K3z0q1u

Comment: it is advised not to try out this in production bucket.

Comment: I was able to get a pem key... Where do you get the cloudfront_key_paid_id? Is that the pem name? I tried the name of the pem in the aws web console but that resulted in access denied. thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55090/discussion-between-paritosh-piplewar-and-anapprentice).

Comment: Also, I tried the first idea, and needed to update the last line to: `"//" + cloudfront_domain + url` for a valid url

Comment: I was wondering to try to access assets/bucket-file in some tricky way. But the risk is involved, you should better try out this thing in some non-production bucket

Answer (score 0):

Use the [aws sdk gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby).

See the [API Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html)

Details about generating a [presigned URL for an operation on the object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#url_for-instance_method)

Provide the access-key-id and secret-access-key:-

```
S3 = AWS::S3.new(
 :access_key_id => 'access_key_id',
 :secret_access_key => 'secret_access_key')
```

In controller put these lines:--

```
bucket = S3.buckets['bucket_name']
s3_obj = bucket.objects["Path-to-file"]
return s3_obj.url_for(:read, :expires => 60*60).to_s
```

This link will expires in 1 Hour. After that the link will be not accessible.

Comment: Thanks but how is that any different, it's not providing the Cloudfront URL?